# Google App Engine Python, query from related entities

Tags: google-app-engine-python

I have two entity which has one-to-many relationships. `Sahip` entity may have multiple `Calisma`.

```
class Sahip(ndb.Model):
    customid=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    adi=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    soyadi=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    ozgecmis=ndb.TextProperty()
    tipi=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True
```

For this aim I've use `KeyProperty`

```
class Calisma(ndb.Model):
    sahibi_fk=ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Sahip,indexed=True)
    sahibi=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True) #fk
    adi=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    yapimyili=ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)
    yapimteknigi=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    en=ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)
    boy=ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)
    derinlik=ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)
    detay=ndb.TextProperty()
```

I am inserting new entity in this way:

```
entity=Calisma()  
entity.adi=adi  
entity.yapimyili=int(yapimyili) 
entity.yapimteknigi=yapimteknigi
entity.en=int(en)  entity.boy=int(boy) 
entity.derinlik=int(derinlik)  
entity.detay=detay entity.tip=tip  
entity.sahibi=sahibi 
entity.sahibi_fk=ndb.Key(Sahip,sahibi) 
entity.put()
```

However, this query is not work:

```
class agah(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        sahip=Sahip.query(Sahip.customid=="suat-atan-1966").get()
        calisma=Calisma.query(Calisma.sahibi_fk==sahip.key)
        m="***"
        for i in calisma:
            m=m+i.adi+"<br>"
        self.response.write(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `query().get()` call returns **a list** of results (possibly empty), not a single result.

In your case:

```
sahip=Sahip.query(Sahip.customid=="suat-atan-1966").get()
```

means that `sahip` is a list, so `sahip.key` should produce:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'key'

The fix could be along these lines:

```
results = Sahip.query(Sahip.customid=="suat-atan-1966").get()
if results:
    sahip = results[0]
    calisma=Calisma.query(Calisma.sahibi_fk==sahip.key)
```